# React line chart background fill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have a line chart in my React application created using **Chart.js** library. The line chart has a background fill applied to it, but I'm facing an issue where the fill covers the y-axis border between 0 and the first data point. I want the border to be drawn over the background color so that it's visible.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const Graph = ({ chartData, chartColour, chartFillColour }) => {

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const data = {
    labels: chartData.labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: chartData.data,
        backgroundColor: chartFillColour,
        borderColor: chartColour,
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
      }
    ]
  }

  return chartData.labels ? <Line data={data} options={options}/> : null;
}

export default Graph;
```

Is there a way to ensure that the border is drawn over the background color? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the drawTime of the fillerPlugin to `beforeDraw` so it draws the fill before chart.js draws any of its own components.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/charts/area.html#configuration

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        datasets: []
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            filler: {
                drawTime: 'beforeDraw'
            }
        }
    }
});
```